# Error happens after setting up a schedule for the change of product info

Tags: magento, magento2

I set up a schedule to update product information for this on admin.

after that, Error happens as below and I can't remove or edit schedule that I set up.

[image]

Step to reproduce

1. Admin > catalog > product> any sku
2. set up schedule (Cilick schedule new update on the top of right side)
3. Select Save as a new update
4. make a change for anything (product name, special price, attribute
5. save
6. Error happens

Same schedule issue

When accessing Content -> Content Staging -> Dashboard. It shows the following screen

[image]

On Debug Identifed there is one request (mui/index/render/...) sent which getting the error

[image]

When checking the log the error is showing

> report.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No
> such entity. at
> /app/45161sdf485ads/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/GroupRepository.php:70)"}
> []

Magento Enterprise Version = 2.4.3-p3

If you have any idea about this issue then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We have identified the reason for this issue: In the past, we deleted some stores and this admin user role has those store id in the related table. That's why this issue was occurring.

So we need to remove values from table authorization_role column gws_websites and gws_store_groups based on the deleted stores.

[image]

I hope it will save time :)